# mysqli php select most recent entries asc

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

query DESC= most recent. query asc = oldest. Im just trying to get most recent entries to display ASC. Using php assoc while loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,userto,userfrom,message,dated FROM emailtable WHERE (userto='$email2 AND userfrom='$email1') OR (userto='$email1 AND userfrom='$email2') ORDER BY dated DESC LIMIT 10";
```

How should I get most recent entries to display ASC?

Comment: Select by `DESC` ~> store in array variable ~> `array_reverse()`

Comment: while ($row = array_reverse(mysqli_fetch_array($querym, MYSQLI_ASSOC))) {

Comment: like that would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let PHP do some work as well, if you just select the 10 newest using `DESC` in SQL you can use `array_reverse()` to display the results in order.

```
$list = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach(array_reverse($list) as $row){
  // oldest in list first.
}
```

Alternatively, without `array_reverse()`:

```
for($i = count($list) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
  print_r($list[$i]);
}
```

Comment: where would that work in conjunction with the while loop, just before it?

Comment: That while loop is not needed if you use `fetch_all()`.

Comment: IT EVEN WORKS IN JS, just to jsonencode then parse in js, then use arrayvar.reverse(); thank you very much Xorifelse

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: @stkmedia Added an alternative to `array_reverse()` as well, JavaScript equivalent would be `list.length`.